# Python show output of remote SSH command in web page in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a simple Django app to show the output of an SSH remote command.

`views.py`:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from subprocess import *

def index(request):
    with open('/home/python/django/cron/sites.txt', 'r') as file:
        for site in file:
            # out = getoutput(f"ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new -p1994 root@{site} crontab -l")
            out = run(["ssh", "-o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new", "-p1994", f"root@{site}".strip(), "crontab", "-l"])
    return HttpResponse(out)
```

`urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
# imported views
from cron import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # configured the url
    path('',views.index, name="homepage")
]
```

`sites.txt`:

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
```

The issue is when I run `localhost:5000`, I see this:

```
CompletedProcess(args=['ssh', '-o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new', '-p1994', 'root@3.3.3.3', 'crontab', '-l'], returncode=0)
```

While I should see something like this:

```
* * * * * ls
* * * * * date
* * * * * pwd
```

I tried with both `run` and `getoutput`, but they either don't connect or the output is shown in terminal only.

How can I run this and show the output in the webpage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning the [CompletedProcess object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess) instead of its output.

Try updating the `run` command to capture output by adding the optional parameter

```
out = run([...], capture_output=True)
```

AND changing the output to show the stdout instead of the object

```
return HttpResponse(out.stdout)
```

Comment: With `run` command when I enter `localhost:5000`, I see the word `None`. I also tried writing that in another file and then reading from second file, but I still see `None`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I updated my answer.  You may need to also experiment with the stdout parameter to run.